# $B$-admissible p-adic representations definitions and implications (Berger article)

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am currently reading [this](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/laurent.berger/autrestextes/barcelone.pdf) article by Laurent Berger about $p-$adic Galois representations and I have some question regarding its section $4$.

I will go through some of its lines and ask my questions in what follows. Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ and $G_K$ denote its absolute Galois group.

- We start with a $\mathbb Q_p$-algebra $B$, endowed with a $G_K$ action.
- The author also assumes that

> (1) $B$ is a domain such that $\text{Frac}(B)^{G_K}=B^{G_K}$
>
> (2) If $y\in B$ is such that the line $\mathbb Q_p\cdot y$ is stable under $G_K$, then $y\in B^{\times}$.

I am not exactly sure in (1) what $G_K$-action are we assuming on $\text{Frac}(B)$, but I suppose it is expected one by declaring $\sigma\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right):=\dfrac{\sigma(a)}{\sigma(b)}$.
To me it seems that condition $(1)$ means that $B^{G_K}\subset B^{\times}$.
The other condition is clear.

- Next, if $V$ is $p-$adic representation of $G_K$, we let $D_B(V):=(B\otimes_{\mathbb Q_p}V)^{G_K}$ and this is a $B^{G_K}$ vector space.
  Then the author continues:

> There is a natural map 
>   $$
> \alpha: B\otimes_{B^{G_K}} D_B(V)\rightarrow B\otimes_{\mathbb Q_p}V
> $$
>
> By condition (1) above the map is injective.

I assume this map should be given by $\alpha(b\otimes v)=bv$. But I don't understand how does condition $(1)$ imply its injectivity.

- Finally, the above injectivity implies that $\dim_{B^{G_K}} D_B(V)\le \dim_{\mathbb Q_p}V$ and if equality holds, the author calls $V$ to be $B$-admissible.
  He claims:

> $V$ is $B-$admissible iff $\alpha$ is surjective.

I do understand the converse direction, but I still can't prove the opposite.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: I stumbled upon this exact problem a few weeks ago. After looking up the proofs in an alternative source ([here, Thm 5.2.1(1)](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/notes.pdf)), I'm pretty sure I wouldn't have been able to figure them out on my own! I don't think these deductions are supposed to be obvious.